# How do you vertical align the div's within a container div vertically to the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have everything vertically aligned to the bottom so that the phone numbers are right above the `<hr>` line rather than way at the top.

```html
<div>
 <div style="float:left; text-align: left;">
  Name<br/>
  555 main street<br/>
  City, State<br/>
  Country<br/>
  Zip<br/>
 </div>
 <div style="float:right; text-align: right;">
  Phone: 555-555-5555<br/>
  Cell: 555-555-5555<br/>
 </div>
</div>
<hr style="clear:left; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use flex like this :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end; /* this will apply the bottom alignement*/
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    Name<br/> 555 main street<br/> City, State<br/> Country
    <br/> Zip
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    Phone: 555-555-5555<br/> Cell: 555-555-5555<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<hr style="clear:left; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
```

Also another solution with inline-block elements (for old browsers if needed):

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0; /* remove white spaces*/
}

.container>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    Name<br/> 555 main street<br/> City, State<br/> Country
    <br/> Zip
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    Phone: 555-555-5555<br/> Cell: 555-555-5555<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<hr style="clear:left; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
```